# use @contextmenu event with vuetify v-data-table

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to build a custom contextmenu that pops up when right-clicking a row in the v-data-table component .

how can I achieve that ?

Comment: please share some code and what you have tried so far

Comment: its not a bug or an error , simply a vuetify thing I don't know how to implement .. I am trying to fire a contextmenu event on each row of the v-data-table and dont know how .. the documentation doesnt contain such a thing and I dont want to use v-slot on the entire row because I have some customized fields already and I dont want to customize the entire row entries..

Comment: what do you want with that event?

Comment: just to show custom contextmenu , a set of actions to be applied on some selected row on the table , I want to take the data from the vue component model itself

Comment: but you should use custom row rendering with slots and fire that event in each row

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 ways to accomplish that.

## Using regular v-data-table rows

Simply add the `contextmenu:row` event listen to the `v-data-table` component, and enjoy the magic of each row emitting this event on right-click. Capture this event and handle it on JS.

```
<v-data-table :items="myItems"
              :headers="headers"
              @contextmenu:row="rightClickHandler"
              ...
/>
```

Then you do whatever you want with the event and the item emitting that event

```
methods: {
  rightClickHandler(event, item) {
    // do something with event and/or item
    console.log(event, item)
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** will not emit when table rows are defined through a slot such as item or body.

## Using table with `item` / `body` slots

When using slots to cutom build your own table rows, you will need to manually trigger the event on each row yourself

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="myItems"
  ...
  <template v-slot:body="{ items }">
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(item, index) in items"
          :key="item.id"
          @contextmenu="rightClick($event, item)"
          ...
```

And on the script side, simply implement the function to handle the event, and the item being clicked on

```
methods: {
  rightClick(event, item) {
    console.log(item)
    event.preventDefault()
  },
```